# Passing strings and ints to multiple activities and databasehelper

Tags: android, database, bundle

I have an app with a "Main" activity that has 8 child activities.  In the main activity I read from a database and load basic info about an item that was selected (via a spinner) into a bundle (this way each activity can load faster because I am not having to query the DB in the onCreate method of that activity to create the view). Once the view is created in the new activity I query the DB for the remaining data needed for that specific activity.  Before now I used public variables which allowed my databasehelper class to know which table to look into to get the data.  I know that is not how you should program so I am converting my app over to using a bundle (not sure if its the best way either but I believe its a step in the right direction).

I am currently able to access the data saved into that bundle in all of my 8 child activities but I cannot access it from my databasehelper class.

my bundle that I use in the main activity:

```
bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putString("KEY_tableName", tableName);
bundle.putInt("KEY_numOne", numOne);
bundle.putInt("KEY_numTwo", numTwo);
... and others
```

**my databasehelper class**:

```
package com.myName.myAPP;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream; 
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//The Android's default system path of your application database.
static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.myName.myApp/databases/";
static String DB_NAME = "databasefile";
public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

//version of database
private static final int version = 1;

public static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
public static final String KEY_TITLE = "Title";
public static final String KEY_BODY = "Content";
public static final String KEY_DATE = "Date";

private static final String TAG = "NotesDbAdapter";
//private static final String DATABASE_CREATE = "create table notes (_id integer primary " +
//      "key autoincrement, " + "title text not null, body text not null);";
//private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "notes";

/**
 * Constructor
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 */
DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
    this.myContext = context;
}

/**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException {

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
    if(dbExist){
        //do nothing - database already exist
    } // end if
    else {
        //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default system path
           //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try {
            copyDataBase(myContext);
        } // end try
        catch (IOException e) {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        } // end catch
    } // end else
    this.close();
} // end createDataBase()

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        //checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
        //File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        //return dbFile.exists();
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e) {
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null) {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase(Context myContext) throws IOException {   

    File fileTest = myContext.getFileStreamPath(DB_NAME);
    boolean exists = fileTest.exists();
    if (!exists) {
        // Open the empty db as the output stream
        OutputStream databaseOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        InputStream databaseInputStream;

        databaseInputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        int length;
        while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } // end while
        databaseInputStream.close();

        databaseInputStream = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);
        while ((length = databaseInputStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            databaseOutputStream.write(buffer);
        } // end while

        // Close the streams
        databaseInputStream.close();
        databaseOutputStream.flush();
        databaseOutputStream.close();
    } // end if
} // end copyDataBase

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException{     
    File f = new File(DB_PATH);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        f.mkdir();
    }
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
} // end openDataBase

@Override
public void close() {
    if(myDataBase != null) {
        myDataBase.close();
    }
    super.close();
} // end close

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
} // end onCreate

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to " + newVersion 
            + ", which will destroy all old data");
    db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS notes");
    onCreate(db);
} // end onUpgrade
```

Plus I have other methods to read/write/update the database.

in my child activities I access the bundle by calling:

```
String tableName = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_tableName");
int numOne = getIntent().getExtras().getString("KEY_numOne");
...
```

in the onCreate method of that activity to be able to use the data

However when I use that code in my methods of my databasehelper class I get an error at: getIntent() and it will not compile in android studio.  The error is:

```
java: cannot find symbol
symbol:   method getIntent()
location: class com.myName.myAPP.DataBaseHelper
```

Thanks for you help.

Comment: You have to paste the code where you are getting the error. Where are you trying to access the getIntent() in DataBaseHelper? and also, as CodeMagic pointed out, you cannot use getIntent() in a non-activity class. When you are retrieving the values in your child activities, pass them to the databasehelper, instead of fetching them again.

Comment: I don't mean to come across as rude but I did give examples of my code and described how it is coded.   I am a self taught programmer and just learned that about intents thanks to @codeMagic.  Can you be more specific to how you recommend to pass them to the databasehelper I was trying to do that with the bundle and intent.  The only other way I know how is with global variables and that is what I am trying to get away from.  Thanks for your advise.

Answer (score 1):

`getIntent()` is an `Avctivity` method so it can't be used in a non-`Activity` class.

[From the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#getIntent%28%29)

> Return the intent that started this activity

but you are not in an `Activity` so it is not recognized

You need to either create a constructor to accept the values you need for your DB or create methods that accept these values and send them from your `Activities`

Comment: can a constructor be used everywhere  or do I need it just for the databasehelper?

Comment: If I understand you correctly, just in the databasehelper. You can send the data through `Activities` with `Intent extras` and `bundles` as you have found. And you can have multiple constructors depending on your needs.

Comment: I am a self taught programmer and have only been able to find examples that use constuctors with intents. Can you point me to some tutorial or code snippets that I can look at?  I dont think I am searching with the proper terms thus not finding the desired results.

Comment: I can try in a little bit but you have a constructor now that takes `Context` as a parameter `DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, version);
    this.myContext = context;
}`

Comment: You can just do it like that with one that takes the params you need. Then that gets called when you create an instance of the class with those params.